# Test cases for media migrating from the file location to a database

Tags: manual-testing

What are the test cases that can be considered on media (pictures) being migrated from  file location to a database?

Comment: Hi user7822, this is a Q&A site.  Do you have a question?

Comment: Can you add any additional details?  Are these pictures then being served up by a web site?  Was the website code changed in order to pull from the new location?  Are you thinking of issues with performance?  Are you asking about tools to verify that the correct image is shown, or that it does not 404, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Some research would have been appreciated. You have not mentioned about file type. Since no details are available I have considered your application does upload and download which in case of upload goes to the database.

1. Check the file size before and after transferred to the database, it should be same.
2. When the file upload is in progress disconnect the internet and connect again, how does your application respond.
3. Does application start data transfer from the beginning or from where it left when the internet was disconnected.
4. Check the same scenaeio for download if internet disconnects while the download is in progress.
5. Does it allows to upload same file more than once or is there any validation. Check FRS.
6. Check for the extension after file upload in database.
7. What is the extension of half file upload on database.
8. File size limitation on upload and download.
9. What is the threshold time set for file upload in case of low internet connectivity.
10. Error on disk full.

There are hundreds of other scenarios.